# Bootstrap-table getHiddenColumns

Tags: bootstrap-table

I want to show the hidden columns (and the values) when clicking on the PLUS icon.
So far I can online show the titles but not the corresponding values :(

I have this function:

```
function FindInVisibleFields() {
  var columns = $('#fresh-table').bootstrapTable('getHiddenColumns');
  var fields = [];
  for (var index in columns){
    fields.push(columns[index].field);
  }
  return fields;
}
```

But that returns: userroleBIGAddressPostalCityenCountry

What I need is:

user: Title and value of hidden column

role: Title and value of hidden column

BIG: Title and value of hidden column

Address: Title and value of hidden column

Postal: Title and value of hidden column

CityenCountry: Title and value of hidden column

I can get the Titles with:

`$.each(columns, function(index, value) { alert(value.title); })`

So, the fields WITH the Titles and values on newlines (That also is a mystery to me :)) 
 or \r\n does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I think that scenario is not supported. Can you explain a little bit more what's your scenario?